# Rails 4.2 constants - where to put them: application.yml vs custom config file.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some constants I am using throughout my app.
I'd say there are three types:

1. some are really passwords to external stuff like sendgrid login/password
2. some are internal "secret codes" like devise secret key
3. some are just what I'd call global constants that is to say there are constants that we use a lot throughout the app and don't want anybody to easily change this. **They nearly never change**. Some examples: the ID of our facebook page, or the number of deals "per page" we define in our infinite scrolling on the homepage (critical for UX), or the url of our brand-validated logo on aws cdn(present in many view files html.erb and assets javascript .js files). One aspect I also have in mind when asking my question, is that even if they seem less critical than a devise key, for those constants, I would like to gather, to make sure very few people and only authorized developers can change those critical data.

Here's what we do today:

- For 1 and 2: I put the constants on config/application.yml
- And for 3 : I put the constants on a custom .rb config file as described by official Rails guide (guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/configuring.html#custom-configuration) 
  For example: on /config/initializers/app_custom.rb

  ```
  Rails.application.configure do        
      config.x.infite_scrollhp_feed_per_page_deals = 30
  end
  ```

then it is called in a controller this way:

```
nb_per_page = Rails.configuration.x.infite_scrollhp_feed_per_page_deals
```

But each time I am unsure if I should put global constants inside config/application.yml or in my custom config .rb file?

What is the recommended "Rails -way"? How to decide where to put them ? Is there a generally accepted "good-sense"/"proven to be efficient/well-structuring" practice/rule ?

Also is there a different in performance that is to say are application.yml "injected" faster into view (.html) and assets(.js) files when user load a page than if they are defined on my custom config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise using `config/secrets.yml` for sensitive data (1 and 2):

```
  development:
    some_password: ...

  test:
    some_password: ...

  production:
    some_password: <%= ENV["SOME_PASSWORD"] %>
```

This way you can put different settings for different environments (for development, test and production).
And I would highly recommend keeping the production sensitive data in `ENV` variables.

When it goes for non sensitive data (3) I would put in `config/environments/*.rb` files when different settings are needed for different environments.
If that's not the case and the setting is the same for all environments, I would put it into `application.rb`, `application.yml` or in a custom file in `initializers/*` or even as class constants.

Comment: then in your vision, what would remain in config/application.yml ? nothing?

Comment: btw, by design the file config/application.yml is not commited inside our repo, so what is inside application.yml remains "secret" :-)

Comment: `application.yml` is also good place to put it when you have the same settings for all envs.

Comment: I would rather commit the `application.yml` to the repo, because the local setup of the app is simpler then. Of course without putting sensitive data there, but fetching them from ENV.

Comment: regarding your last comment, ok but when you say "fetching from ENV", where do you put those ENV ? they're all in in secrets.yml ?

Comment: No, in `secrets.yml` you can read an enviromental variable: `ENV['VARIABLE_NAME']`. But this variable have to be set in your system (for production, directly on production server). You can search google how to set env vriables, eg: "linux how to set environment variables".

Comment: ok thanks, weird. I thought i knew how to do this. in my app the ENV were set in application.yml which was not commited in the repo:)

Comment: Ah.. true. So in your case `application.yml` is used to set the env variables. I didn't picked that up.